# How do I capture the output of oc command : oc get endpoints -n default -o yaml kubernetes inside a redhat ocp container

Tags: go, openshift, redhat-containers

I tried using clientset.CoreV1().Endpoints(namespace).Get(context.TODO(),name string , metav1.GetOptions{})

```
endpoints, err2 := clientset.CoreV1().Endpoints(namespace2).Get(context.TODO(), namespace2, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err2 != nil {
            log.Println(err2.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("GetPodList There are %v endpoints in the cluster\n", (endpoints))
```

But I am unsure of the argument to give for name string (the second argument) and metav1.GetOptions{}. (third argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `List` function rather than `Get`: `List` allows you to retrieve multiple endpoints matching certain criteria, `Get` allows you to retrieve a specific endpoint (by name).

Thus:

```go
endpoints, err := clientset.CoreV1().Endpoints(namespace2).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
// ...
fmt.Printf("GetPodList there are %v endpoints in the cluster\n", len(endpoints.Items)
```

If you want all the endpoints in a namespace, you don’t need to specify any list options and passing an empty structure is fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for writing back. In the list options how do I specifically specify the options " -o yaml kubernetes "?

Comment: I got the right struct values , one small change i this statement : fmt.Printf("GetPodList there are %v endpoints in the cluster\n", len(endpoints.Endpoints) ...endpoints.Endpoints does not work, it has to be endpoints.Items , I then convert that to a string

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, `.Items` indeed.